# I want to use https in opencart checkout page only, the rest page should have http

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, opencart, checkout

I have installed ssl certificate and I want to use https in checkout page only. I have set on the ssl in settings. It's still showing https in all the page.

Please tell me the solution for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Just link appropriately. If you explicitly point to `http://example.com`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencart by default works with ssl only in checkout pages and when user is logged in, as such the only way for you to have https in all url is to force via .htaccess, the simplest solution if this is the case is to remove the redirection that forces https in .htaccess enable ssl in opencart backend and change the config file site url from http to https, although these are steps you should have taken before, and a simple removal of the right lines in .htaccess should suffice.